# How to change options on a collada model in three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js, blender, collada

How would you implement the following in three.js 
e.g
You have a basic car model say collada
The car can have multiple options e.g lights, spoiler, sun roofs, bike rack etc
Based on what the user selects for each option you want to show the car.

My understanding is:
You would have a basic model for the car and then have models for the options.

You load the basic model to your scene, then ...

When the user selects a option you need to add the option to the model.
This is the part I am not sure how to do? Does anybody have some sample code?
Is there another recommended way of doing this?

Comment: You can take a look at http://threejs.org/examples/webgl_materials_cars.html which does exactly what you want.

Comment: This is changing the skins.

Comment: This is changing the skins What I would like to do is say select sun roof, spoiler, rim from a variety for each. There are two things that I want to understand
1) How should the model be create. From what I understand the options will have to be placed in different layers for each option (sun root,spoiler,rim) 
2) Once the model is loaded using three.js how to manipulate so that based on the user selections for the options the car is dispalyed correctly.
So if what I said about the model is correct how to show and hide the layer.

Comment: I looked at this example http://threejs.org/examples/webgl_morphtargets_md2.html 
Based on the users selections different guns are displayed. 
I want to do the same thing but instead have a car and more then one thing (instead of a weapon) to select.
All the cars available are not MD2 so ideally would like to use collada or three.js models.